# jQuery, simultaneours ajax calls and $.when

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

When using $.ajax().done, at the moment, you can do something neat like :

```
$.getJSON('url').done(myFn);
$.getJSON('url2').done(myFn2);
```

But when you are using $.when with the same 2 ajax calls, you are required to perform a "strange" thing

```
$.when($.getJSON('url'), $.getJSON('url2')).done(function(res1, res2) {
    myFn(res1[0], res1[1], res1[2]);
    myFn2(res2[0], res2[1], res2[2]);
});
```

Would there be a way to do something like :

```
$.when($.getJSON('url'), $.getJSON('url2')).done(myFn, myFn2);
```

That is, when you are passing multiple functions to done, they are resolved for each argument, in the same order ?

Edit : here comes more informations from my wished use case :

```
$.when($.getJSON('tweets'), $.getJSON('users'))
    .done(rememberTweets, rememberUsers)
    .done(displayTweetsWithUsers)
```

At the moment, I do :

```
var tweets, users;
$.when($.getJSON('tweets'), $.getJSON('users'))
    .done(function(tweetsRes, usersRes) { 
         tweets = tweetsRes[0]; 
         users = usersRes[0];
         displayTweetsWithUsers();
    });
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. Do you mean you don't want to wait for both requests to be done, but fire their `.done()` callbacks individually? Then why would you want to use `$.when`?

Comment: In my case, I would like to have :  $.when($.getJSON('url'), $.getJSON('url2')).done(myFn, myFn2).done(myContinuationFn);

That is, myFn and myFn2 are remembering data for the myContinuationFn but I'd like to keep it separated from data dealing.

Does it make sense now ?

Comment: Your current code looks like a mess. Why do you use global `tweets` and `users` variables, and why don't you pass anything to that display function? Not exactly good practise.

Comment: Thé variables are scoped in a closure used for a jqury pluGin. so these vars are used by other methods. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you are required to perform a "strange" thing

Not really, I think your syntax expresses quite well what you are doing. If you think there should be a shorthand - no, there is none, because what you want to do *is* strange (an unusual use case).

If you need a generic version of this, use

```
function zipMapper(fns) {
    return function() {
        var args = arguments;
        return fns.map(function(f, i) {
            return args[i].length ? f.apply(this, args[i]) : f.call(this, args[i]);
        }, this);
    };
}

$.when($.getJSON('url'), $.getJSON('url2')).then(zipMapper([myFn, myFn2]);
```